# How to define Intervals for a uniform probability distribution?

Tags: math, random, probability

I do not know its the right forum to ask question, however i will appreciate if someone can help me.

I have two processes and each have a distinct random Variable , let say X1 & X2, each Random Variable is from a uniform distribution with [0,1], then how random.nextdouble() can help me to identify the variation between the probabilities of these two random variables. I need this variation because i want to find the probability of minimum of the two random variables.

Can I say that its too simple and I should run the program for 100000 or more times twice and then count the minimum value from two iterations? If so, then how can I map this result with probabilities of two random variables i.e. X1 & X2?? Like what is the criteria to say that the first time I ran the program was for X1 and 2nd time for X2.

Comment: 1) Is `random` so poor that you must take 100000 draws before they start to look random? 2) What does "how can I map this result..." mean? 3) "What is the criteria...": just say that the first time was for X1, and the second time was for X2; what's the problem?

Comment: @Beta 1. its not that poor.. i just gave the rough idea
2. Mapping means random variables X1 & X2 with real processes.. is it okay to say as you have mentioned "just say that the first time was for X1 and second was for X2? it was only my query.. i was not sure about it.. so that is why i asked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of a single variable under uniform distribution to be under `d` is `P(X<=dx) = d` (assuming in range `[0,1]`).

Thus, the probability of it to be more then `d` is `P(X>=d) = (1-d)`.

The probability of 2 random variables to be above d is `P(X>=d AND Y>=d) = P(X>=d)*P(Y>=d) = (1-d)^2`

Thus, the probability that one of `X` or `Y` to be under `d` is `p = 1-(1-d)^2`, and this means that the probability of the minimum to be under `d` is the same: `p  = 1 - (1-d)^2`.

If you are looking for the probability density function, you can just find the derivitive of the probability:

```
f(x) = d/dx P(x) = d/dx 1 - (1-x)^2 = 
     = d/dx (1 - 1 + 2x - x^2) = 
     = d/dx (2x - x^2) = 2 - 2x
```

Comment: Well, Amit thanks for your answer, but what i was looking for is its implementation using c#, thats why i placed my question here..Infact i am confused in first how to find the probability of minimum of two random variables.. X1 & X2 and 2nd how can i use random.nextdouble() function

Comment: @amw, amit has given you the probability density, which is the first half of what you seem to be asking for. As for generating the minimum of two random variables, I'd say generate the two variables and take the minimum. What's the problem?

Comment: @Beta i do not have any issue with Amit's answer.. but i wanted to know its implementation.... may be your comments have given me the idea.. thanks